# filter floating point in matrix or cell array

Tags: matlab

The cell array consists of 400x1 elements in double (and may extend to 1,000,000 x 1).
I would like to filter all entry with -1.000.
What is the best way to filter floating value? 
Should I do it in cell array or matrix?
Or should I do it by just creating a for loop, runs through each element, and store non -1.000 entry into new array?

I read the value from file using textscan, and later convert it to matrix in order to plot a cdf graph. However I'd like to eliminate all entry with -1 from the graph.

---

```
fid = fopen('t1_error.txt','r');
C = textscan(fid, '%.3f');            
fclose(fid);

A = cell2mat(C);
[ycdf,xcdf] = cdfcalc(A);
ycdf = ycdf(2:length(ycdf));
plot(xcdf, ycdf, 'LineWidth', 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ansari has the right idea, but I'm pretty sure in your case there is no need to look at the tolerance since -1 is a flag for an invalid value, and is represented exactly in floating point, and therefore you won't get any weird rounding issues which the tolerance trick is meant to resolve.

```
Z = (A == -1);   % Z(i) = 1 if A(i) == -1,
                 %        0 otherwise

A1 = A(~Z);      % Subset of A excluding all -1 values.
```

Comment: I could achieve it with A(A == -1.0000) = []; , length(A) change before and after this line, and the difference is exactly same as number of -1 entries in the array. However thanks for your idea, learnt another way of filtering!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do something like

```
tolerance = 1e-6;
A(A+1 < tolerance) = [];
```

to filter out the values that are very close to `-1` after setting the tolerance to some acceptable value for your application.

Comment: C is a cell type, and matlab returns "Undefined function 'plus' for input arguments of type 'cell'." ....

Comment: You want to check proximity to -1, so you check the value of `A - (-1)`

Answer (score 0):

you NEVER write a for loop in Matlab, unless you tried every other possibilities ;) Remember, it is matrix oriented programming.

If you want to filter out -1, just do :

```
A = magic(6);
A(1,3) = -1.23;
A(2:4,3:5) = -1.00;
% the -1.23 value is preserved by the following line
A(A==-1.0000) = 0;
```

Or if you want to know where those -1 are :

```
A = magic(6);
A(2:4,3:5) = -1;
minus_one_loc = find(A == -1);
A(minus_one_loc) = 0;
```

So, this is the answer if I understand well what you wanted.

cheers

Comment: What is the difference between a) A(A==-1.0000) = 0  vs. (b) A(A==-1.0000) = [].   There are still some entries which is -1.000 after running (a), whereas all -1.000 entries were removed with (b).

Comment: A is a matrix, so your (b) won't work. And no, with A(A==-1.000) = 0, there are no more -1.000 in your matrix. They are replaced with 0.